# iOS app submission dependencies

Tags: ios, deployment, store, distribution, submission

I am about to set up a deployment team for iOS app submission. Here are a couple of questions:

1. Can the engineering team send the deployment team the archive rather than source code? The archive will be code signed with the distribution certificate by a team admin assigned in the engineering team
2. I assume that multiple macs can be used for deployment which means export the private key of distribution certificate and import to another mac will not invalidate the original one. And as to question 1, the archive exported from a private key "activated" mac and signed with the distribution certificate will work as the same on another private key "activated" mac. The archive is exported by pressing the "distribute" button in the archive organizer and choose "Export as Xcode archive" and can be also done by a team admin. Are these assumptions correct?
3. Noticed from Apple doc,now team admins can also create distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile. Does it mean the only thing that is unique for a team agent to do is to press the "distribute" button in an archive organizer and select "Submit to iOS app store" as well as the following procedures?

Many thanks if anyone can anwser these questions. The major objective is identify if there are limitations of Roles and machine dependency

Comment: Can you give a little more background?  Why do you need a team of people to deploy?  If the engineering team is going to be signing the build for distribution, why are you asking about copying the distribution keys for deployment?